# Error when making a Flask Application available on my LAN

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am trying to **make my Flask Application available on my home network**, so that I can view it from a different computer *(that does not contain the source code)*. However, i am getting an error when i try running it.

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port="0000")
```

It still throws an error even when the port number is intuitively set as an integer

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=0000)
```

This is the error:
**raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot bind to a random port with enabled reloader if the Python interpreter does not support socket opening by fd.**

Comment: If you don't care about the port number, try assigning it an actual value that you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```

If this does not work, then it's probably a CORS issue.

Then

1.First install flask-cors using `pip install flask-cors`

2.Import it in your project `from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin`

3.Start your app like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```